# How to use SDL functions like SDL_DestroyTexture() properly?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am doing [this](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php) lazyfoo SDL tutorial right now.

The render class they using has some image to texture function which is using  `SDL_Surface*` and  `SDL_Texture`.
At the end of the function they "free" the created surface by calling `SDL_FreeSurface()`.

Now, I am wondering:

1. Why exactly i have to free the Surface at all (variables are local?)?
2. Why its ok to let the created Texture be without calling `SDL_DestroyTexture`?
3. What exacty does it mean when i destroy a texture or free a surface?

```
    bool Tile::loadTexture(const char* path){  
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;  
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path);  
    //...some code  
    Texture = newTexture;  
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);         
    return Texture != NULL;}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `fopen`/`fclose`? The situation with those functions is similar.

Answer (score 4):

> Why exactly i have to free the Surface at all (variables are local?)?

The pointer `loadedSurface` is local. The actual surface isn't: there is something similar to `malloc` inside of `IMG_Load`. The same way you use `free` on memory allocated with `malloc`, you use `SDL_FreeSurface` on surfaces allocated with `IMG_Load` (or `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` and so on).

> Why its ok to let the created Texture be without calling SDL_DestroyTexture?

`SDL_DestroyTexture` is called, inside of `LTexture::free`, which is called by the destructor of `LTexture`. So `SDL_DestroyTexture` is pretty much guaranteed to be called at some point if `loadFromFile` was called.

> What exacty does it mean when i destroy a texture or free a surface?

It means the same thing as using `free` on memory allocated with `malloc`, or using `delete` on memory allocated with `new`, or calling `std::unique_ptr::reset` (without argument), and so on. Each variant does something sligthly different. If you want to know what exactly differs between `SDL_DestroyTexture`, `SDL_FreeSurface`, `free`, etc, you can look at the source code: SDL is open source and there are quite a few open source implementations of `free` out there.

Comment: the free funktion uses SDL_DestroyTexture for the one texture "mTexture" declared inside of the class but not for the texture declared inside of the loadFromFile function "newTexture". i will take a other look on the memory allocation stuff. thank yo so far

Comment: The second last instruction in `loadFromFile`, `mTexture = newTexture;`, makes `mTexture` hold the texture before `newTexture` goes out of scope. It's still the same texture though, only its address is being copied. I actually don't know why the author uses a local variable here instead of directly using `mTexture`. It's functionally the same, but would be less confusing.